# visual studio customize the default build properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

MyApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">    

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Configurations>Release</Configurations>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64' And '$(TargetFramework)'=='net5.0-windows' And '$(RuntimeIdentifier)'=='win-x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\app\</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>my-app</AssemblyName>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86' And '$(TargetFramework)'=='net5.0-windows' And '$(RuntimeIdentifier)'=='win-x86'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\x86\app\</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>my-app</AssemblyName>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>      
</Project>
```

these commands build both x64 and x86 assemblies in "....\app" and "....\x86\app" folders

```
msbuild.exe "MyApp.csproj" /t:restore;rebuild /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64
msbuild.exe "MyApp.csproj" /t:restore;rebuild /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x86
```

but clicking Build (Ctrl+F5) or Debug (F5) in Visual Studio outputs to "bin\Release\net5.0-windows" directory.

how to force Build (Ctrl+F5) and Debug (F5) to do the same as this command:

```
msbuild.exe "MyApp.csproj" /t:restore;rebuild /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64
```

Comment: When you build in Visual Studio, is your active "configuration/platform" set to "Release/Any CPU"? Does changing the platform to 'x64' change the `OutputPath` to "..\..\app\"?

Comment: Set AnyCpu to x64 or x86 in the configuration manager, then Build and Debug can do the same thing as the command?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Changing the configuration manger to Release|x64 outputs to bin\x64\Release\net5.0-windows

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <Configurations>Release</Configurations>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <OutputPath>..\..\app\</OutputPath>
        <AssemblyName>my-app</AssemblyName>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
        <OutputPath>..\..\x86\app\</OutputPath>
        <AssemblyName>my-app</AssemblyName>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You can refer to the following steps to solve this problem:

1.Select target framework .net5.0-windows

[image]

2.Choose Platform x86

[image]

3.Debug your project with the button or F5

[image]

4.Change Platform x64 and Debug it.

5.Finally we can get these folders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to put `net48` before `net5.0-windows` in `<TargetFrameworks>` to use the designer and that generates this error: `Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\my-app.exe.config" because it was not found`, also I need to generate assemblies for win-x64 runtime directly without generating `runtimes` folder that contains all runtimes (unix, linux-x64, win, win-x86,...)

Comment: also the designer crashes when setting the platform to `x64` (`AnyCPU` works well)

Comment: What is the error when setting the platform to x64? It works fine in my test.

Comment: the designer crashes and this error appears: `Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\my-app.exe.config" because it was not found` I think because of setting `net48` before `net5.0-windows` in `<TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: I tried to set net48 before net5.0-windows in <TargetFrameworks>, but still cannot reproduce the error. Maybe you can try to delete the obj folder, unload and reload the project and try again.

Comment: yes it works by deleting the obj folder but it generates output for net48 not net5.0-windows, also runtimes folder is genereated. how to force the generation of net5.0-windows assemblies for win-x64 runtime only?

Comment: @geek175 See step1 click the arrow next to button can choose Framework.

Comment: net5.0-windows is selected

Comment: @geek175 I did a lot of tests but couldn't reproduce your problem, maybe you changed some settings before. You can try to create a new project and follow my steps to check if the same problem still occurs. Or you can provide sample to help me to reproduce this problem